# Is electric field independent of electric charge?

Tags: electrostatics, maxwell-equations

We have Poisson's equation ,

${ \nabla  }^{ 2 }\varphi =\frac { \rho  }{ { \varepsilon  }_{ 0 } } $

Which reduces to Laplace's Equation,

${ \nabla  }^{ 2 }\varphi =0$

And we see that there are non-trivial solution to Laplace's Equation. Now in Laplace's equation there are no electric charges present in the whole of space and yet we have non-trivial solutions.

- Does this mean that we can have electric fields without any charge?
- Which is more fundamental, field or charge?

Comment: It means that you can have an electric field in a region where there are no charges present ie between the plates of a parallel plate capacitor.

Comment: 1) Yes 2) In what sense?

Comment: @knzhou Does charge arise as a consequence of the field or the other way around?

Comment: @Farcher Can there be a field without charge in whole of space?

Comment: The electromagneitc field has an electric field component, so in a universe with only photons there would be electric fields

Answer (score 0):

1. There can definitely be field in the regions where there is no charge. One example is mentioned in the comments - Between the capacitor plates. You can think of many more. Electric field by a positive charge can be experienced in the regions where there is no charge. Although, the experiences, i.e. the effect, of the field can be done with the help of a test charge. How much force the field exerts on the test charge determines how the field affects the test charge.
2. Charge doesn't arise as a consequence of field. Field can be understood as the effect of that charge at various distances, thus the effects of that charge takes different numerical values at different positions. These values are field, kind of. Gravitational field is another field which doesn't need or generate charge. This field describes how an object can be affected due to the Gravitational force of another body, not necessarily in the vicinity, at various distances.

Answer (score 0):

1. Laplacian is second derivative. If it this equal to zero everywhere it means there are no local maxima or minima (of course except when maybe boundary conditions are imposed). So when a region has constant field $0$, everywhere has to have that value. No charge in any place means no static electric field.
2. Depends on what fundamental means. When you ask which produces which, charges seem more fundamental. There is no field if there's no charge present somewhere.